# Multiple WebClient calls from worker threads get blocked in loopback requests back to self

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a .NET 4.5.2 ASP.NET webapp in which a chunk of code makes async webclient calls back into web pages inside the same webapp. (Yes, my webapp makes async calls back into itself.) It does this in order to screen scrape, grab the html, and hand it to a PDF generator.

I had this all working...except that it was very slow because there are about 15 labor-intensive reports that take roughly 3 seconds each, or *45 seconds in total*. Since that is so slow I attempted to generate all these concurrently in parallel, and that's when things hit the fan.

What is happening is that my aspx reports (that get hit by webclient) never make it past the class constructor until timeout. Page_Load doesn't get hit until timeout, or any other page events. The report generation (and webclient calls) are triggered when the user clicks Save in the webapp, and a bunch of stuff happens, including this async page generation activity. The webapp requires windows authentication which I'm handling fine.

So when the multithreaded stuff kicks off, a bunch of webclient requests are made, and they all get stuck in the reports' class contructor for a few minutes, and then time out. During/after timeout, session data is cleared, and when that happens, the reports cannot get their data.

Here is the multithreaded code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(folders, ( folderPath ) =>
{
    ...
    string html = getReportHTML(fullReportURL, aspNetSessionID);
    // hand html to the PDF generator here...
    ...
});

private string getReportHTML( string url, string aspNetSessionID ) {
    using( WebClient webClient = new WebClient() ) {
       webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
       webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "ASP.NET_SessionId=" + aspNetSessionID);
       string fullReportURL = url;
       byte[] reportBytes = webClient.DownloadData(fullReportURL);
       if( reportBytes != null && reportBytes.Length > 0 ) {
          string html = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reportBytes);
          return html;
       }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Important points:

1. Notice I have to include the ASP.NET session cookie, or the web call doesn't work.
2. `webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true` is required for the winauth.
3. The fragile session state and architecture is not changeable in the short term - it's an old and massive webapp and I am stuck with it. The reports are complex and rely heavily on session state (and prior to session state many db lookups and calcs are occurring.
4. Even though I'm calling reports from my webapp to my same webapp, I must use an absolute url - relative URL throws errors.
5. When I extract the code samples above into a separate .net console app, it works well, and doesn't get stuck in the constructor. Because of this, the issue must lie (at least in part) in the fact that *my web app is making async calls back to itself*. I don't know how to avoid doing this. I even flirted with `Server.Execute()` which really blows up inside worker threads.
6. The reports cannot be generated in a windows service or some other process - it must be linked to the webapp's save event.

There's a lot going on here, but I think the most fundamental question/problem is that these concurrent webclient calls hit the ASPX pages and get stuck in the constructor, going no further into page events. And after about 2 minutes, all those threads flood down into the page events, where failures occur because the main webapp's session state is no longer active.

Chicken or egg: I don't know whether the threads unblock and eventually hit page events because the session state was cleared, or the other way around. Or maybe there is no connection.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using DownloadDataAsync?

Comment: Wow, this is very promising, I feel dumb. Thank you.

Comment: If the page which generates the report uses Session then that's the problem, when a request uses the session the session gets locked and until it isn't finished the next can't continue.